# get multiple arrays in json in Android using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

How to create a correct pojo class for the below json and display the "mcategory_id" and "effect_list" in textview using Retrofit 2

```
     {  
   "categories":[  
  {  

      "mcategory_id":"14"
  }  
                ],

   "effect_list":{  
       "14":[  
  {  
       "effects_id":"164"
  }        
            ]
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link to create your java file 
[JsonToJavaConversion](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)

Answer (score 0):

You will have a class Category with attribute mcategory_id.
Then you will have a class effect_list which will contain a list of items that contains "effects_id".
So basically you will need 4 classes.

Class Category with mcategory_id.

Class Effects with effects_id.

Class Effect_list (in your json is a object not a list) which will contain a list of Effects ("14" name in your json)

And a response class for your retrofit:
Retrofit class will contain List of Category("categories"called in your json) and a object of Effect_list(called "effect_list" in your json).

Use annotation @SerializedName so that you can map easily the json into your objects.